# How to extend grants in MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb, sql-grant

I want to execute command

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

But I have error:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'%' (using password: NO)
```

When I check my grants I have `USAGE`, nothing more.

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW GRANTS;
+----------------------------------+
| Grants for root@%                |
+----------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' |
+----------------------------------+
```

Command

```
CREATE DATABASE test;
```

Does not work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO root@localhost IDENTIFIED BY '...' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

But, if you don't have `SUPER` privilege to get in to do it, see the manual page for how to get in (*from the same server*) using `--skip-grant-tables`

Answer (score 1):

The error message tells you that you don't have the right privileges to modify user grants.

You need the [`GRANT OPTION`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/grant/#the-grant-option-privilege) and `ALL PRIVILEGES` grants to be able to grant them to other user (yourself included).

Comment: Yes. You are right, but how to obtain `GRANT OPTION` and `ALL PRIVILEGES`?

Comment: Someone with those grants must give them to you. With a fresh installation, the user would be `root@localhost`. Make sure you connect through the UNIX socket, that way it'll use the `localhost` hostname.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by commands

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-\*
sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client
```

found at

> https://askubuntu.com/questions/643251/having-trouble-installing-and-removing-mysql-in-ubuntu

But I am curious if there is no such invasive solution.